# How to apply OData query to stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi project that use OData for query the result of api and I have a stored procedure in SQL Server like this.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Something]
    (@select nvarchar(500)='select *', @query nvarchar(max)='')
as
begin
    declare @q nvarchar(max)

    set @q = @select + ' from #prs1 ' + @query;
    print @q

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @q
end
```

So I don't want to execute this stored procedure without any filter because of performance issue.

I want to know how to get translated OData query to SQL Server or query expression and pass them to my stored procedure.

My C# (Entity Framework) code:

```
var res = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Product>("Something @select,@query" new SqlParameter("@select", slct), new SqlParameter("@query", query));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Having such an "execute all" stored procedure might look like a good idea at first - but it'll come back and haunt you and cause you grief and trouble over and over and over again later on. Don't do this - seriously - just don't. This opens the doors to sooooooo many issues (like SQL injection and many more). Don't do this. Seriously. If you want to use stored procedure - make them do **one thing and one thing only** - don't use "do it all" approaches, those never work long term. **DON'T DO IT!**

Comment: Thanks for your reply marc_s. But when OData translate queries doesn't check for these kinds of issue?

Comment: No, OData does nothing of that kind

Answer (score 1):

To add to @marc_s's comment above.  The generic execute sql procedure is a bad idea.  Also, the Web API/OData libraries are not generating SQL - EntityFramework is.  If you want to intercept the odata query and use it to generate appropriate parameters for a stored procedure, look at adding ODataQueryOptions...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj890615(v=vs.118).aspx

...to your controller method.  Use this to understand the request and generate an appropriate call to a procedure.